# form input field "sometimes" gets set to disabled"" rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble with a form input field. There is no real rhyme to its reason it happens sometimes on full page reload ie clicking the browser refresh. I can get it to work if I click on another link in the page and then another link back to the original address, or simply clicking a direct link to the current/same page.

Usually when its turbolinks you need to add `..on.('turbolinks:load', function` but its just a form field which is handled by turboliinks already, so its really confusing me.

This is the html when the button is functioning

```
<input name="commit" value="Post" id="formsubmit" data-disable-with="Create Micropost" type="submit">
```

and when it is not functioning it has `disabled=""`

```
<input name="commit" value="Post" id="formsubmit" data-disable-with="Create Micropost" disabled="" type="submit">
```

The input fields have some turbolinks jquery attached to them but its the same both situations. Its not the table dimension thing either when you put your form inside a `<td>` tag. I really cant figure it out?

I can post my form details but its seems the same as my other forms. No errors in the server except for `unpermitted parameter picture_cache` but  dont think thats it.

Edit: Here is the form code

```
<section class="micropost_form">
<%= form_for(@micropost, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= gravatar_for(current_user, size: 30) %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new post..." %>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-file">
    <label for="micropost_picture" onclick="showBrowseInput()">Choose File</label>
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :picture_cache, :value => f.object.picture_cache %>
    <button class="imagelinkbtn" type="button" onclick="showImageInput()">Image Link</button>
    <button class="videolinkbtn" type="button" onclick="showVideoInput()">Embed Video</button>
    <button class="giflinkbtn" type="button" onclick="showGifInput()">Embed Gif</button>
  </div>
  <div class="media_field_1">    
    Image <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="media_field_2"> 
    Video <%= f.text_field :video_url, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div> 
  <div class="media_field_3"> 
    Gif <%= f.text_field :gif_url %>
  </div>  
  <div class="thumb">
    <% if f.object.picture.url.present? %>
    <%= image_tag f.object.picture.url %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="media-preview" style='position:relative;height:300px'>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit value: "Post", id: "formsubmit" %>
<% end %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "media_preview_script" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "picture_file_upload_size_limit" %>
</section>
```

Comment: Does the behaviour persist in a different browser ?

Comment: I would have to check that as I can reload the page over ten times with the same result, thats a good idea I will use chrome or edge from now on and see if it happens. Iam using firefox BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

*Turn off autocomplete in form*

```
= form_for @user, html: { autocomplete: "off" } do |f|
```

Comment: I think this is right  I tested it a good few days and hasnt failed. There is more you can find on the issue [here](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/585) and [here](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/26) Thanks krishnar.